# How find column letter by column name to use in SUM formula in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a formula SUM in a Cell in VBA but I don't know which Column letter I need to sum. I know the column Name that it's equal to "AMOUNT" and the line that is locate the header of the line 25.

```
Sample: The column J line 25 has the header "Amount", so my formula needs to be equal below:

Range("N22").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=SUM(J26:J999999)"
```

So, I need a code in VBA to find the letter J to put in my formula below.

```
Range("N22").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=SUM(J26:J999999)"
```

Comment: Is vba really necessary, as this can be done with a simple formula: `=SUM(INDEX(26:999999,0,MATCH("Amount",25:25,0)))`

Comment: If you want vba to put the formula in then `Range("N22").Formula = "=SUM(INDEX(26:999999,0,MATCH(""Amount"",25:25,0)))"`

Comment: Scott, perfect.... I used the formula that you send me in the vba and it works perfect. thanks a lot.